# How can I add an integer value to current hour value and display it to the user?

Tags: c

I am getting current date and time and then I ask the user how many hours they would like to sleep.

I try to add that value to the current date and time to calculate when they would wake up.

The issue is that compiler only returns me this even I put a print function:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 12.599 s
```

How can I add integer values to current hour and display that time?

This is the function that I have:

```
void goToSleep(int *sleep) {
    int sleepAmount;

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    printf("Current time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
    printf("How many hours do you want to sleep? ");
    scanf("%d", &sleepAmount);

    int wakeUpHour = tm.tm_hour + sleepAmount;

    // Adjust sleep need based on the user input
    // Note the use of atoi, which converts the input to a number.
    *sleep += sleepAmount;

    printf("After sleeping for %d hours, your sleep need is: %d\n", sleepAmount, *sleep);
    printf("Current time is %d\n", wakeUpHour);
}
```

Here is the full code that was asked in the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NEED_COUNT 9

void welcomeMessage(char *name, int *needs) {
    printf("Welcome!\n");
    printf("Needs Levels: Hunger:%d, Sleep:%d, Love:%d, Socialization:%d, Health:%d, Education:%d, Hygiene:%d, Toilet:%d, Entertainment:%d\n",
           needs[0], needs[1], needs[2], needs[3], needs[4], needs[5], needs[6], needs[7], needs[8]);
    printf("To-Do List:\n");
    printf("1. Eat\n");
    printf("2. Sleep\n");
    // ... Other operations
    printf("0. Exit\n"); }

void eatFood(int *hunger) {
    char food[50];
    int amount;

    printf("What will you eat? ");
    scanf("%s", food);
    printf("How many will you eat? ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    // Increase hunger level based on need
    // Note the use of atoi, which converts the input to a number.
    *hunger += amount * 5;

    printf("After eating %d %s, hunger level: %d\n", amount, food, *hunger); }

void sleepDuration(int *sleep) {
    int sleepAmount;

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    printf("Current time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
    printf("How many hours do you want to sleep? ");
    scanf("%d", &sleepAmount);

    int wakeUpHour = tm.tm_hour + sleepAmount;

    // Adjust sleep need based on the user input
    // Note the use of atoi, which converts the input to a number.
    *sleep += sleepAmount;

    printf("After sleeping for %d hours, sleep need is: %d\n", sleepAmount, *sleep);
    printf("Current time is %d\n", wakeUpHour); }

// Other functions can be implemented in a similar manner

int main() {
    char name[20];
    int needs[NEED_COUNT] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}; // Initial needs

    printf("Welcome to the Virtual Baby Application!\n");
    printf("Enter your baby's name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    int choice;
    do
    {
        welcomeMessage(name, needs);
        printf("Choose an operation (0-Exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            eatFood(&needs[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            sleepDuration(&needs[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            eatFood(&needs[2]);
            break;
        case 4:
            eatFood(&needs[3]);
            break;
        // Other cases can be added here
        case 0:
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Try again.\n");
        }
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that error `0xc0000005` is an access violation error. You have tried to access memory that you don't own.

Comment: `struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, I am new to this platform, and also how can I authorize myself to access that memory?

Comment: That's not the issue. There is a bug, which is accessing memory that you didn't intend to access. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: @AKX — why do you say that `struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);` probably doesn't do what the OP expects?  What does it do in your view?

Comment: You need to show the code calling this function — that is more likely to be the source of trouble than any code here.

Comment: You might need to do some work on the altered `tm` value — using the `mktime()` function.  Otherwise, you're going to claim that the current time is 31 when someone asks for 8 hours sleep at 23:15.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, but it isn't *minimal*. I entered a name and selected 'Sleep' and '2' hours, the program output some details and went back to the menu. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didnt know how to provide Minimal Reproducible Example, so that's why I included for you guys to see the whole code, it is true that I don't know how to format code in this site and I am a newbie but didn't exactly get why my post was closed, can you please provide me sources so next time when I ask a question I can format it and ask it the right way? Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Most platforms have an internal representation of time, so you avoid needing to adjust adjacent fields (e.g changing hours if you add minutes, changing month after subtracting days). In C that's normally `time_t`, which is in seconds, so to add an hour increase it by 3600. `mktime()` converts `struct tm` to `time_t` (and corrects for hourse > 24 etc.), `localtime()` and `localtime_r()` convert back.

Comment: How you do that is to remove parts from the code that aren't necessary to reproduce the specific problem. There are two main reasons, a) so that code is relevant and easy to follow, b) because that act may lead you to the bug anyway. Formatting: copy/paste the code into the question, 'select' or highlight the code, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: @Mehmet Emin, 1) please also post input used. 2) Better code checks the return values of `scanf()` calls.  Consider improving your code.

Comment: @MehmetEmin Comment `Note the use of atoi, which converts the input to a number.` is confusing as code does not call `atoi()` anyplace.